# java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument during socket write

Tags: java, sockets

I have a java1.6 gateway application runs on aix. During the day millions of messages passing through successfully but when I look at logs I see a few logs like stacktrace below.
log1:

```
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:119)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:921)
    at org.mule.providers.http.HttpServerConnection.writeResponse(HttpServerConnection.java:223)
    at com.ibtech.smg.esb.providers.esb.ESBHttpMessageReceiver$NewHttpWorker.run(ESBHttpMessageReceiver.java:162)
    at org.mule.impl.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:290)
```

log2:

```
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:125)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:171)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:119)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:234)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:304)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:308)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:154)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:288)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:266)
    at java.io.FilterWriter.flush(FilterWriter.java:112)
    at org.mule.providers.http.ResponseWriter.flush(ResponseWriter.java:75)
```

I have searched internet but none of the trace or case seem to be fit with mine.
I have tried to generate situation in my development environment (on windows.) Tried big messages, closed socket situations, 0 size messages, but no luck. Can not see the same error. Do anybody has any clue why this error can occur ? This is a bug in application or os bug ?

Comment: Did you already try `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` ? It seems to be a solution on similar questions.

Comment: @user140547 It would be nice if you could add a link to one of the _similar questions_

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216713/java-net-socketexception-invalid-argument-connect
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056399/eclipse-and-tomcat

Comment: I already saw that question, stack trace does not look like mine(I get error in writing to socket). and also I get this error very rare, but the question specifies a permanent error I think.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument) occurs when you try to write a buffer larger than 64K using `SocketOutputStream.write()`.
When you use `SocketOutputStream.write()`, remenber use `SocketOutputStream.flush()` to clear `SocketOutputStream`.

Another situation, connection has closed by server. 
(use command 'netstat' to check status of your connection, will be 'CLOSE_WAIT')
When you using `SocketOutputStream.write()`, log also dispaly "java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument".

[REF_DOC](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7100575)